# typescript switch case for function calls simplification

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to simplify function calls depending on switch conditions using typescript?

for example

```
switch ('type') { case 'apples': { this.apples(); break; } case: 'pears': { this.pears(); break; } case 'lemons': { this.lemons(); break; }
```

simplified to something like this

```
callFruit(type) => { this.'type string here'(); }
```

Comment: `this['apples']()` or with variable: `this[type]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method has the same name as the value you are switching on, and all the functions have the same signature (or compatible signatures) you can just index into the object and call the result:

```
class X {
    apples(){ return  "apples"; }
    pears(){ return  "pears"; }
    lemons(){ return  "lemons"; }

    // We use a genric function to ensure the type of values is a union on literal types not string
    static readonly values = (<T extends string>(v: T[]) => v)(['apples', 'pears', 'lemons'])
    callFunction (type: string){
        const index = X.values.indexOf(type as any);
        //If the value is not in the expected input we raise an error
        if(index == -1) throw "Value not ok";
        // Since values[index] is a union of apples | pears | lemons 
        // the type of this[X.values[index]] will be ()=> string 
        // inferred based on 
        return this[X.values[index]]();

    }
}
```